# incorrect Javascript Object syntax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to create a JavaScript array for Google Analytics.

below is my code. I think the syntax is incorrect. The first part of the syntax is ok, i.e purchase, but I think that I am running into problems when I try to create an array within this object.

```
i.e:      'products': []
```

I am not sure how to add an array to this object.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
 'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
    'actionField': {
            'id': '<?php echo $order->getId()?>',                         // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
            'affiliation': '<?php echo $order->getAffiliation() ?>',
            'revenue': '<?php echo $orderGrandTotal?>',                     // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
            'tax': '<?php echo $orderTax?>',
            'shipping': '<?php echo $orderShippingTotal?>',
            'coupon': '<?php echo $order->getCouponCode() ?>'
        },

        'products': [
            <?php foreach($orderItems as $item): ?>
        <?php $intCtr++;?>
        <?php if($item->getParentItemId()) continue;?>
          {                            

            'name': '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName()) ?>',     // Name or ID is required.

            'id': '<?php echo $item->getSku() ?>',

            'price': '<?php echo ($helper->sendBaseData()==true ? $item->getBasePrice() : $item->getPrice()) ?>',
            'brand': '<?php echo $helper->getBrand($item->getProduct()) ?>',

            'category': '<?php echo $helper->getQuoteCategoryName($item) ?>',

            'quantity': <?php echo $item->getQtyOrdered()?>

            <?php if ($intCtr==count($orderItems)):?>
                        <?php endif;?>  
                }            
                <?php endforeach;?>            
        ]
    },

   }

});
```

Comment: PHP has a built in JSON library. you shoudl use that instead.

Comment: There isn't any JSON in your post, what you have is a JavaScript Object, or an Array of them.

Comment: @LucaKiebel - thanks. i have amended my question

Comment: Along with what Luca mentions, this wouldn't be valid JSON anyway since you are using single quotes, JSON uses double quotes for delimiters

Comment: To clarify: You should build a PHP associative array, in the structure you want, and then convert the entire array to JSON in a single call to `json_encode`. You should not mix JavaScript and PHP inside an object literal like this, it's error-prone and unnecessarily hard to read and debug.

Comment: As for the js you are forming you dont have a trailing comma to separate the different objects, this among other reasons why you should build your array in php first and then use json_encode to generate the correct code

Comment: @PatrickEvans- thank you for advice. is it possible for you to show me what you mean. an example of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I would just do the lot in PHP.

```
$array = [
    'ecommerce' => [
        'purchase' => [
            'id'=> $order->getId(),
            // etc etc
        ],
    ],
];

$json = json_encode($array);
```

Then just echo the lot in one go in your Javascript!

```
{"ecommerce":{"purchase":{"id":12345}}}
```

Comment: i have no idea what you mean. could you please give me a full example

Comment: OK, first. You understand how to build an array?

Comment: hi. yes i do .i understand that part

Comment: So build it all up like that, do the `json_encode()`, then `dataLayer.push(<?= $json; ?>);` in your JS